# How to convert RSA private key to pem

Tags: encryption, rust, cryptography, rsa

I need to convert the private key generated using RsaPrivateKey::new() to pem but can't figure out how to do this through the documentation

```
use rsa::{PublicKey, RsaPrivateKey, RsaPublicKey, PaddingScheme, pkcs8::EncodePrivateKey};

// create a private key
let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
let bits = 2048;
let private_key = RsaPrivateKey::new(&mut rng, bits).expect("Failed to generate key");
// create a public key / address
let public_key = RsaPublicKey::from(&private_key);
```

Creating the pem returns an error saying that LineEnding is undeclared but that is how they do it in the documentation:

```
let priv_pem = RsaPrivateKey::to_pkcs8_pem(&private_key, line_ending: LineEnding::default);
```

Comment: What crate is this? Rsa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import LineEnding from pkcs8, or qualify it as from that crate:

```rs
use rsa::pkcs8::{LineEnding, EncodePrivateKey};

let priv_pem = RsaPrivateKey::to_pkcs8_pem(&private_key, LineEnding::default);
```

or

```rs
use rsa::pkcs8::{self, EncodePrivateKey};

let priv_pem = RsaPrivateKey::to_pkcs8_pem(&private_key, pkcs8::LineEnding::default);
```